# How to implement "appendFile" function?

Tags: ocaml

I can use the following function to overwrite a text file:

```
let writeFile ~filename:fn s =
let oc = open_out fn in
    output_string oc s;
    close_out oc ;;
```

Howeve, i donot know how to append a line to a text file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass additional mode flag `Open_append` to `open_out_gen` function:

```
let _ =
    let oc = open_out_gen [Open_creat; Open_text; Open_append] 0o640 "a.txt" in
    output_string oc "append\n";
    close_out oc
```

Comment: Good idea.  I wasn't sure what the semantics were, but it appears that `Open_append` just seeks to the end of the file for you.  (I thought it might use Unix `O_APPEND`, which causes every write to append to the file, no matter where the file position is.)

Comment: Whoops, my test was wrong.  `Open_append` *does* cause every write to append to the file.  So you should use it carefully, only when that's what you really want to do.  Regards,

Comment: @JeffreyScofield: you are right, the file can not be seeked if opened in `append` mode (same as `fopen` in c).

Comment: (Technically in c if you open in a+ mode, you can seek for reading, but writes still go to the end.  There's no update mode in the OCaml pervasives, though.)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do:

```
let append_string path s =
    let chan = open_out_gen [Open_wronly; Open_creat] 0o666 path
    in let len = out_channel_length chan
    in
        begin
        seek_out chan len;
        output_string chan s;
        close_out chan;
        end
```