# How to print into file in OCaml in a appending way?

Tags: ocaml

Currently I have some code in this way:

```
       method printFuncIntoFile X = 
          let funHead = "head"
          and funbody = "body"
          and oc = open_out "test.txt" in
          Printf.fprintf oc "%s%s" funHead funBody;
          close_out oc;
          foo X.child
```

And this code can only leave the last function content in the text.txt.

I search the Printf [document](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) but can only find a

```
val bprintf : Buffer.t -> ('a, Buffer.t, unit) format -> 'a
```

which requires a Buffer data structure, I think there should be some strategies more easy, even though I don't know

So my question is that:

How to print into file in OCaml in a appending way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement "appendFile" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090490/how-to-implement-appendfile-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
open_out_gen [Open_append; Open_creat] 0o666 "test.txt"
```

Note that opening channels isn't part of Printf, but part of the [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) module.